# cocos2d-x 3 add a Sprite into a Layout

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

When I do this it works:

```
Layout* layout = Layout::create();
layout->setLayoutType(Layout::Type::HORIZONTAL);
layout->setContentSize(Size(280, 150));
layout->setPosition(Vec2(visibleOrigin.x + 100, visibleOrigin.y + visibleSize.height - 100));

addChild(layout);

auto jacket = Button::create("jacket.png", "jacket.png", "jacket.png", Widget::TextureResType::PLIST);
layout->addChild(jacket);
```

But when I do this (**add a Sprite instead of the button added in above code**):

```
Layout* layout = Layout::create();
layout->setLayoutType(Layout::Type::HORIZONTAL);
layout->setContentSize(Size(280, 150));
layout->setPosition(Vec2(visibleOrigin.x + 100, visibleOrigin.y + visibleSize.height - 100));

addChild(layout);

auto jacket = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("jacket.png");
layout->addChild(jacket);
```

Then I get assertion fail on line `layout->addChild(jacket);` with the message `Expression: vector subscript out of range`. I suppose sprites are not supported in Layouts? Then what is the right way to add and image into a layout? Should I use `ImageView` as below?

```
auto jacket = ImageView::create("jacket.png",TextureResType::PLIST);
layout->addChild(jacket);
```

If yes then why? and what is the difference of `Sprite` and `Image`?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, the button will try to load the individual file named "jacket.png" whereas the createWithSpriteFrameName initializer will try to get the jacket.png frame from a previously loaded texture atlas

The problem could be as simple as the jacket image not being in a texture atlas or the atlas (frames) not being loaded before running this code

Comment: No, this is not the case. I preload asynchronously and only then change the scene to the one where I show this UI elements. Also see `Widget::TextureResType::PLIST` parameter while creating the button. This means use loaded texture and not an individual file. Hecne, if "jacket.png" is loaded for the button then it is obviously loaded for being used for sprite too.

Comment: Ah, that's what that TextureResType means. Have you tried adding the sprite directly to the scene rather than layout? To see whether the sprite is working or not in general.

Comment: Tried. Works! `ImageView` also work. Therefore, I conclude, Sprite is not possible to add into the Layout and hence `ImageView` is created.